# convert datetime to string and format

Tags: python, string, sorting, datetime, format

I have the following list that contains dates (but not formatted as datetime, only strings):

```
MyList = ['25/4/2014', '2/12/2014', '15/7/2014']
```

I want to sort this list from earliest date to the latest date.
I put together the following code:

```
MyList = ['25/4/2014', '2/12/2014', '15/7/2014']
MyList2 = []
for i in MyList:
    MyList2.append(datetime.strptime(i, "%d/%m/%Y"))
SortedList = sorted(MyList2)

Result = []
for n in SortedList:
    m = n.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    Result.append(m)
print Result
```

The list gets sorted, but the problem is that the format is slightly different:
    ['25/04/2014', '15/07/2014', '02/12/2014']

Notice the extra "0" in the day and month numbers.

Is there any way to get the resulting list to have the original format where for example the month of April will be "4" and not "04"?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Use a `key` function with `sorted()`; this'll parse the dates *just for sorting*, leaving the original values untouched:

```
SortedList = sorted(MyList, key=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

The list is then sorted on the return values of the `key` function instead of the values themselves. Internally, Python *decorates* the values (produces tuples of `(key(v), None, v)`,  with `None` making sure `v` is not involved in breaking ties), sorts these, then un-decorates again.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> MyList = ['25/4/2014', '2/12/2014', '15/7/2014']
>>> sorted(MyList, key=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, "%d/%m/%Y"))
['25/4/2014', '15/7/2014', '2/12/2014']
```